# AngularJS - how to fake a server to get local json file in project?

Tags: angularjs, json, http, server

I am making a local static webpage that has no backend. I've only got data in a json file. I will be zipping up the code and sending it to someone.

I cannot import the file into index.html because the code that needs it (a factory) is separate in a factory.js file.
e.g.

```
<script src="LOCAL.js"></script>
```

Won't work because i don't do any logic on the index.html page.

I cannot do $http because I get a cross domain error and it's not acceptable.

How can I get my json file locally into my factory? I have NodeJS and NPM. However, the person I'm sending the webpage to will also need to run it without any problems.

Comment: Use a cors enabled cloud service

Answer (score 1):

You could mock out a service that just fetches a JSON file and loads it in, or you could mock the JSON out directly in the script.

If you wanted to do a service, you could try something like

```
module.exports = {
  getJSON: function() {
    return $http.get('./path/to/file.json')
      .then(function(json){
        //do something with your json
        return json;
      })
  },

  getJSONObject: function() {
    return {
      // add your json in here //
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried that but then I get a browser error regarding cross domain. It's not allowed for this project.

Comment: Can you edit the CORS policies? if you can't, your only other option here is to include the JSON directly in a JS file and return it like you would a server call. This should not violate CORS and will give you mock functionality. You could add in a setTimeout as well to mock server delays.